# What is the difference Jpa Criteria Api isFalse and isTrue?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, specifications, jpa-criteria

I have this examples ,but I can't solved difference between them. Both of them are creating same query.

```
public static Specification<TransactionProjection> hasDestinationPartyNumber(List<PartyNumber> values) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(values)) return not();
    return (root, query, cb) -> cb.isTrue(root.get(TransactionProjection_.column1).in(values));
}

public static Specification<TransactionProjection> hasNotDestinationPartyNumber(List<PartyNumber> values) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(values)) return not();
    return (root, query, cb) -> cb.isFalse(root.get(TransactionProjection_.column1).in(values));
}
```

Comment: I think the reason might be because logical tests in SQL do not have an intrinsic boolean value. Try using `root.get(TransactionProjection_.column1).in(values)` directly for the first `Predicate` and `cb.not(...)` instead of `cb.isFalse(...)` for the second one

Comment: @crizzis I didn't understand what do you mean logical tests in SQL do not have intrinsic boolean value ? ı try  cb.not () and thats work.but ı am wondering what is the difference between isFalse and isTrue ?

Comment: See my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I haven't tested my answer, and `isTrue(...)/isFalse(...)` is poorly documented.

I *think* the reason why `isTrue(...)/isFalse(...)` has no effect in your example is that logical tests in SQL (and, by extension, in JPQL/Criteria API, in order for it to be easily translatable to SQL) do not have a boolean value (in fact, *they are not r-values at all*). For instance, the expression `WHERE (a IN (1, 2, 3)) = TRUE` is invalid, since the `a IN (1, 2, 3)` part **does not evaluate to anything**.

`isTrue(...)/isFalse(...)` is meant to be applied to expressions that *have an actual value*. For example, if the `TransactionProjection` entity had a `boolean active` property, then it would make sense to use `cb.isTrue(root.get(TransactionProjection_.active))` or `cb.isFalse(root.get(TransactionProjection_.active))`.

I'm surprised that a query syntax exception wasn't thrown in your example, though, it might be a bug of the JPA implementation.